# Does the rlt8821ce WiFi chip support “monitor” mode

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

Does it support the monitor mode (known from aircrack-ng)?

`"iw list"` shows that there is no "monitor" mode support on this chip.

```
Supported interface modes:
* IBSS
* managed
* AP
* P2P-client
* P2P-GO
```

**However**, question is --

Is this a driver issue and by recompiling we can enable "monitor" mode OR is this the chipset limitation ?

Comment: Have you tried to put it in monitor mode? I literally have never had to use the "iw" command in Kali.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart yes, it gives me error